# Why the number keeps showing up? [Guess the number]

Tags: c++, debugging

I want to add a function to check if the user is input numbers or not but the numbers just keep showing up.
The game and the input check works fine, but what as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int guessnum; 
    int ansnum = rand() % 100+1;
    int upi = 100;
    int lowi = 1;
    cout << "Guess the number(1-100): " << '\n';
    cin >> guessnum; 
    do{
        while (!cin)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Input A number(1-100): "<<'\n';
            std::string ignoreline; getline(cin, ignoreline);
            guessnum;
            continue;
        }
        if (guessnum < ansnum)
        {
            lowi = guessnum;
            cout << lowi <<" - "<<upi<<'\n';
        }
        else 
        {
            upi = guessnum;
            cout << lowi <<" - "<<upi<<'\n';
        }
        cout << "Guess the number again: ";
        cin >> guessnum;
        
    }
    while (guessnum != ansnum);
    cout << "Congratulation! You WIN!";
    return 0;
}
```

I want it stop showing the "0-100" after the instruction.

Now is like this:
`Guess the number again: s Input A number(1-100):  0 - 100`

Comment: What do you think the statement `guessnum;` does?

Comment: You have `guessnum;` by itself, which does nothing. Did you mean to write `cin >> guessnum`?

Comment: I also suspect the [input stream `ignore` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Sidenote: `continue;` as the last thing in a loop is pointless.

Comment: @AinzOoal There is another, more subtle, bug in the program though. Test it like this:  Hardcode `ansnum = 50;` and then guess 50. You would expect the program to then write _"Congratulation! You WIN!"_, right?